# Libgit2sharp. Ошибка: failed to lock file for writing. Как решить?

Tags: c#, git

При клонировании репозитория с помощью libgit2sharp ошибка: failed to lock file " ..../.git/config,lock" for writing: "C:\project\libgit2sharp\Core\Ensure.cs"

Я нашёл аналогичные вопросы и вижу как все пишут:

> Just for reference, this is a serious issue with parallel runners in GitVersionTask: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/1381.

Там я нашёл https://github.com/gittools/GitVersion/releases/tag/5.6.9

Я просто не пойму как это использовать. Мог бы подсказать кто?

Comment: _параллельными бегунами_ - Google Translate чтоли? И что именно вы хотите использовать?

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли у пользователя право на создание файла внутри папки .git

Comment: Может создавать.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла обычная обработка этой ошибки. Вроде проблем от такого пока не увидел.